# Find list of xml elements that have a list of names using linq (and remove them)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML

```
<itemList>
  <Item>
    <shipAddress></shipAddress>
    <shipMethod></shipMethod>
    <rate>50.00</rate>
    <custom>
        <custcol_1>55</custcol_1>
        <custcol_2>60</custcol_2>
    </custom>
    <special>
       <special1>A</special1>
    </special>
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <shipAddress></shipAddress>
     <rate>50.00</rate>
     <custom>
        <custcol_1>7889</custcol_1>
        <custcol_2>754</custcol_2>
     </custom>
 </Item>  
</itemList>
```

What I am trying to do is gather a list any nodes that are `<custom>`  or `<special>` because I want to remove them.

I tried to do that with  the following but it didnt get any nodes:

```
nodesToRemove = xeConsolItm.Elements()
    .Where(itm =>
    (
        itm.Element("custom") != null &&
        itm.Element("special") != null &&
        itm.Element("other") != null
    ))
    .ToList();


foreach (var xElement in nodesToRemove)
{
    nodesToRemove.Remove();
}
```

I also tried the same with `||` but that didn't work either. In both cases the `nodesToRemove` ends up empty.

I wondered a way to do that.
I have been able to do it by removing each at a time but when I try to merge the 3 together, I have no luck. Is the best way to just do one at a time?

Comment: i should note that currently xeCosolItm is an XElement

Comment: Not a XML expert, but shouldn't `nodesToRemove.Remove();` be `xElement.Remove();` or `xConsolItm.Remove(xElement);`?

Comment: Your XML document is not valid. It doesn't have a closing tag for `<itemList>` and the closing tag in this line doesn't match the openning tag: `<spec1>A</special1>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Descendants()` instead of `Elements()` to get elements on any depth.

Also you should use the `Name` property to get the name of the element.

```
var nodesToRemove = xeConsolItm.Descendants()
    .Where(itm =>
        itm.Name == "custom" || itm.Name == "special" || itm.Name == "other")
    .ToList();
```

Also you need to fix the loop as noted in the comments.

```
foreach (var xElement in nodesToRemove)
{
    xElement.Remove();
}
```

A simpler version as suggested by @CharlesMager is this:

```
xeConsolItm.Descendants()
    .Where(itm =>
        itm.Name == "custom" || itm.Name == "special" || itm.Name == "other").Remove();
```

Comment: Possible simplification is that `Remove` is defined as an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` for `T is XNode`.  So there's no need to call `ToList` and the loop can be replaced with `nodesToRemove.Remove()`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesMager, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

@YacoubMassad's answer is correct and will give you the expected result. Here's a different (admittedly not as clean) way to get the result, following your existing syntax:

```
var nodesToRemove = xeConsolItm.Elements().Nodes()
                                     .Where(itm => 
                                        itm.ToString().Contains("custom") || 
                                        itm.ToString().Contains("special") || 
                                        itm.ToString().Contains("other")).ToList();

foreach (var xElement in nodesToRemove)
{
    xElement.Remove();
}
```

There are a couple issues with your current code, namely:

- You're selecting `Elements`, not `Nodes`
- You won't find a `Node` that contains `"custom" && "special" && "other"`
- Trying to do `nodesToRemove.Remove()` as mentioned in the comments instead of `xElement.Remove();`

You can still select `Elements` from `xeConsolItm`, but the results will give you the entire `<Item></Item> Element` instead of just the `<custom>/<special>/<other> Node`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest create a class and then deserialize/serialize.

With the class you have full control and it's easier to work.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="shipAddress")]
        public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="shipMethod")]
        public string ShipMethod { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="rate")]
        public string Rate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="custom")]
        public Dictionary<string,int> Custom { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="special")]
        public Dictionary<string,int>Special { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="itemList")]
    public class ItemList
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Item")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When properties have different names I use Dictionary and then you can use LINQ to access them.

Get value of a dictionary:

```
var valueOfFirstSpecialElement = Special.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Use XmlSerializer to Serialize/Deserialize:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

In your case if you don't want Custom and Special just remove the properties from the class and after deserialize the class won't have them.

Comment: there is an issue with this one for me because though my example had a few elements, the actual xml has many many and they can be somewhat dynamic past the few that were listed so this is not so easy a solution.   Hence my working with the xml itself